# Mat Dialog boxes close button is not working on IOS devices

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, mat-dialog

Im using **Angular 13** for my application. And I used **angular-material** *Mat-Dialog box* as a pop up modal. This is the ***HTML*** code of the submit and close buttons.

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
<button class="btn" mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="closeModal()">
  <span class="btn-text">CLOSE</span>
</button>
<button class="btn" mat-raised-button style="background-color: #CF466F;" (click)="deleteAd(data.id)">
  <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span *ngIf="!loading" class="btn-text">YES, DELETE</span>
</button>
```

Everything worked properly in **Desktop** & **Android** mobile devices. But it's not working properly in **IOS** devices. Here submit button is functioning as expected in my I phone (**IOS version 12.5.5**). But the **close** button is not working. And when the modal is poped up, it cant be closed since the close button is not functioning.

This is my ***Typescript*** code.

```
closeModal(): void {
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this.dialogRef.close();
});
```

}

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is thare a reason you run this.dialogRef.close() inside a ngZone.run ?

Comment: closeModal(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close();
}

Comment: This also gave same thing.

Comment: Must be some wierd bug, you can try you use mat-dialog-close directive on the button as well instead for the click binding.

Comment: @Dasaya_Developer did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in closing mat-dialog issue in my application which is in  angular14 later i upgraded into angular15, i fixed this issue by adding polyfills for latest javascript features

for that i have installed some dependencies

```
1) npm i core-js
2)npm install --save web-animations-js
```

i added these polyfills to my polyfills.ts file

after my pollyfills.ts looks like

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

import 'core-js';

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```

you can configure importing core.js by adding specific features only by referring documentation https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#readme

below article helpmed me to reach at this solution https://dev.to/coly010/angular-how-to-support-ie11-4924

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Angular version 13.2.0. I have another project with version 13.0.2 and there it works. It also did not work with version 14 or a higher 13.x for me.

So a quick fix would be downgrading.

Comment: iam using angular 14.x iam also facing same issue in iphone 8 plus ?did you found any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem! You have to disable animations for IOS <=13 !

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45016

app.module.ts

```
const disableAnimations = !('animate' in document.documentElement) || (navigator && /iPhone OS (8|9|10|11|12|13)_/.test(navigator.userAgent));


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule.withConfig({ disableAnimations }),
...
```